# Checking if data is clojure code and running it

Tags: parsing, clojure, sandbox

I want to parse and run (clojure) code from untrusted sources 
in clojure and if possible in clojurescript.

---

Example:
User enters code in webbrowser -> cljs detects if code is valid and gives feedback.

Code goes to server -> initiate sandbox run the code or do code analysis

---

What is the best way to do that.
How are other websites (running untrusted code) doing that and what libaries should I use.

I found [clojail](https://github.com/Raynes/clojail) but the last commit is 5 years old.
And [tools.reader](https://github.com/clojure/tools.reader) which does parsing if I'm correct.

Any help is welcome :)

Comment: This may not be the comment you're looking for, but I think it is worth considering anyway.
You want to allow people to run Clojure code. This can be a security risk because people may try to trick your application into running code on your server that you don't want.
If I were you, I'd only do this when I fully understand how that process is working. Without wanting to be insulting, your question comes across as a bit newbie-ish and you could run into problems.
Just my 2ct, to be taken with a grain of salt...

Comment: What do you want the code to do? You might be better off with a small DSL that restricts the effects the user can cause? Or you could just run the code in the client's browser itself.

Comment: I'm well aware of the risks.  
My intention is to execute little functions to check if thoses solve a given unit test.
I would like to run code client and serverside.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need [read](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/read) or [read-string](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/read-string). This will read a stream or string as Clojure data.

Assuming you know and understand the risks, you could then use eval to evaluate it as code. This is essentially what the [repl](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/main.clj) is doing.

Note that the clojail library you reference offers a safer replacement to eval, where you can restrict certain operations. It is used by https://www.4clojure.com/